# CSS3 transform vertical align text glitch

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using a CSS3 vertical align method using transform to vertically align my div which contains text and text link content. Good thing is that it works, bad thing is that on chrome, the text seems to wiggle whenever the mouse hovers over the text.

EDIT: It mostly happens with a tags, if you scroll down the test site to the image posts and hover the mouse on and off the text and then back on again, you will be able to the the wiggle easily.

```
Test site = http://fivdiv.tumblr.com/

/*CSS*/
.tile-text-wrapper.photo {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
left: 10px;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%)
}

<!-- HTML markup -->
<div class="tile-text-wrapper photo">
    <a class="tile-title photo" href="#">Link Text</a>
    <a class="tile-read-more photo" href="#"><small>Photo Post</small></a>
</div>
```

Would much appreciate if anyone could help me figure out how to get the text to stop wiggling when :hover.

Thanks !

Comment: it seems it happens on window greater than `1240px`

Comment: I do not see any issue or wiggle on the ( a ) tags I am on a 15in macbook any other way of reproducing the effect?

Comment: Hi Enjayy, I can say I know of another way, however, are you using safari ? If not, if you check that link demo site i gave, scroll down to the twitter feed and if you hover over the first tweet text "After jerez test..." and off and then on, you will see all the text in the text wrapper jump up and down. Hover on, hover off, hover on, hover off is the only way i can see to reproduce it.

Comment: Yea, I can't reproduce the wiggle. I wouldn't recommend using `transform` for positioning as it is probably more hardware intensive than necessary for positioning a tags. You can nest a relative div with `width: 100%` inside of the absolute div and use padding.

Comment: I'm not seeing a jitter on my machine, but I have "fixed" similar problems in the past by experimenting with forcing hardware acceleration `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` and opacity `opacity: 0.99;` — might help...

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I will try that out asap and let you know how it goes.